# return checked in modal

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem returning 'checked' on my modal, here's the problem

I have these tabel called role_has_permissions that have permission_id that got foreign key from permission tabel.

[image]

*note: a Role could have many permissions like this:

[image]

In controller I already success returning permissions as usual, but the problem is when I tried to match the id value from permissions tabel with role_has_permissions

In Controller I do like this..

```php
$permissions = DB::table('permissions')->get();
$role_permissions = DB::table('role_has_permissions')->join('permissions', 'role_has_permissions.permission_id', '=', 'permissions.id')->get();
return view('role.index', compact('role', 'permissions', 'role_permissions'));
```

In view:

```
@foreach ($permissions as $i)
    @foreach ($role_permissions as $item)
        <div class="form-check ps-1 mt-2">
            <input {{ $i->id == $item->permission_id ? 'checked' : '' }} disabled id="{{ $i->id }}" name="permissions_id[]" class="form-check-input form-disabled" type="checkbox" value="{{ $i->id }}">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ $i->id }}">{{ $i->name }}</label>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

The result is not like what I expected. how do I have to do this properly?

Comment: Hi @Fragmantedbin, what result are you getting if you run var_dump or dd?

Comment: @OliverKucharzewski dd($role_permissions) it would return multiple same role_id with different  permission_id and id 'from permissions tabel'

Answer (score 0):

multiple `foreach` should not use in this case for eg:

UserListPermission
UserCreatePermission

the first `foreach` will loop two times

Admin->UserListPermission

The inner loop will check roles two times.

```
$admin->UserListPermission == UserListPermission
$admin->UserListPermission == UserCreatePermission
```

which is no of use instead of that we can get role permissions Id array as below

```
$permissions = DB::table('permissions')->get();
$role_permissions = DB::table('role_has_permissions')->join('permissions', 'role_has_permissions.permission_id', '=', 'permissions.id')->pluck('permission_id')->toArray();
```

return view('role.index', compact('role', 'permissions', 'role_permissions'));

and on the view page:

```
@foreach ($permissions as $i)
    @php $checked = in_array($i->id, $role_permissions) ? 'checked' : ''; @endphp
    <div class="form-check ps-1 mt-2">
        <input {{ $checked }} disabled id="{{ $i->id }}" name="permissions_id[]" class="form-check-input form-disabled" type="checkbox" value="{{ $i->id }}">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ $i->id }}">{{ $i->name }}</label>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Hope it will be helpful.